# Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'conv1/7x7_s2/bn'; shape mismatch. Caffe Error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I trained pretrained GoogleNet(caffe) on Digits. The training went well and testing in Digits UI show no problem whatsoever. But when I export model and try to use example.py that digits provided. This error came up.

> Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'conv1/7x7_s2/bn'; shape mismatc
>   h.  Source param shape is 1 64 1 1 (64); target param shape is 64 (64). To learn this layer's parameters from sc
>   ratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer.

I have checked the deploy.prototxt and train_val.prototxt. The dimension is correct.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `'deploy.prototxt'` for layer `'conv1/7x7_s2/bn'`. Add

```
param {
  share_mode: PERMISSIVE
}
```

For each of the trainable parameters of the layer.

See [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L305-L313) for more information.

Comment: Every layer in the deploy.prototxt? Why example.py of digits can't classify it. I mean I use digits to train but can't use example.py to test it.

Comment: @asiandudeCom you only need to add it to the `param` of the problematic layer. I don't know why you are getting this error - something about dimensionality...